# How to use an array for a parameter in typescript? Cannot find name 'array' (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am learning Typescript and I am changing existing files in a React app from `js` to `tsx`.

For the code below I pass in an array of `posts`.

I've change the file extension to `.tsx` and I then change the signature from

```
export default function PostList ({ posts = [] }) {
```

to

```
export default function PostList ({ posts = [] }: { posts: array}) {
```

but I get

```
TypeScript error: Cannot find name 'array'.  TS2304
```

Rest of the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Post from './Post'

export default function PostList ({ posts = [] }: { posts: array}) {
  const sortedPosts = posts.sort((postA,postB) => {
    return Date.parse(postB.created) - Date.parse(postA.created);
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      {sortedPosts.map((p, i) => (
        <React.Fragment key={'post-' + i}>
          <Post {...p} />
          <hr />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Read the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use the type of the elements followed by `[]` to denote an array of that element type:

```
const numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

The second way uses a generic array type, `Array<elemType>`:

```
const numbers: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).

In your case, `posts` can be described like:

```
posts: Post[]
```

where `Post` interface has to be defined like:

```
interface Post {
   id: number;
   ...
}
```